# Clear asp.net form at runtime

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Whats the easiest way to clear an asp.net form at runtime using c#.

Thanks
Sp

Comment: What do you mean by "at runtime"? Does this mean when the user is viewing the page?

Comment: If you're talking about doing this client side, then use form.reset()

Comment: @Jeff Schumacher  Forgot that one.... Another option is put a Reset button <input type='reset'> on the form

Comment: Im trying to clear the controls serverside.
Once the user submits a form i dont want them to be able to see the data again - thats why i want to re set it serverside
Thanks for your comments guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following JS/c# to clear the form.

c# to add the js call onload

```
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(WebForm3), "ClearPage", "ClearForm();", true);
```

the JS to clear the form

```
function ClearForm() {
            var AllControls = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PnlAll')
            var Inputs = AllControls.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (var y = 0; y < Inputs.length; y++) {
                // define element type
                type = Inputs[y].type
                // alert before erasing form element
                //alert('form='+x+' element='+y+' type='+type);
                // switch on element type
                switch (type) {
                    case "text":
                    case "textarea":
                    case "password":
                        //case "hidden":
                        Inputs[y].value = "";
                        break;



                }
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to clear input boxes, dropdowns etc. This can be done the following way in code to recursivly clear all data.

```
foreach( var control in this.Controls )
{
   ClearControl( control );
}
```

and the recursive function

```
private void ClearControl( Control control )
{
    var textbox = control as TextBox;
    if (textbox != null)
        textbox.Text = string.Empty;

    var dropDownList = control as DropDownList;
    if (dropDownList != null)
        dropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;

    // handle any other control //

    foreach( Control childControl in control.Controls )
    {
        ClearControl( childControl );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, i was unable to get it working as im using HTML controls, I switched the textbox to htmlinputtext but still failed.
I have used some js to clear the form
Thanks for your post
Sp